# How to change the value of a row in views

Tags: views

I've views formatted as table with a pager of 10 items pr page, in which I've a field called type, depending on that type, I need to modify the other field, show text.

I've tried using PHP global field, but when I put that it is not showing the checkboxes from the second page.

I've tried hook_views_pre_render, but did'nt see any good example to change the field.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> - Equal To
> - Not Equal To
> - Greater Than
> - Less Than
> - Empty
> - Not Empty
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

As per the [readme.txt](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_conditional/tree/README.txt)

> How to use Views Conditional:
>
> 1. Create a view. Add some fields under "FIELDS".
> 2. Click on "ADD" next to fields. Scroll down to "Views: Views Conditional", probably found near the bottom of the list.
> 3. Add and configure fields...
> 4. Choose a field to run a condition against, and provide values accordingly.
> 5. Save, views conditional handles the logic and returns as specified.

Comment: Can we do it programmatically using any hooks?

Comment: I've done it in D7, in D8 not yet, but I bet you can. Tho, I am too lazy right now to look into it.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra you could create a template file views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig template file and do it there too.

Comment: I've done that and failed.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra post your template code, if you still have it.

Comment: I've created views-view-table--new-products--page-1.htnl.twig. and it didn't work.

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra show me what you put insider of it.